# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByClassName(...).Click is not a function at <anonymous>:1:109

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("panel11-7-b").getElementsByClassName("btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton").click();
```

I am trying to make it click a button but it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByClassName(...).Click is not a function
>       at :1:109

Comment: getElement**s**ByClassName returns an array, which doesn't contain `click`in its definition.

Comment: because a HTMLCollection does not have click

Comment: @lilezek it is not an Array. It is Array like. :)

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection, you can't call `click()` on it.

you need to traverse through the collection and call click on individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I solved my own problem lol

document.getElementById("panel11-7-b").getElementsByClassName("btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton")[0].click();

Comment: This code assigns the click event only to the first element from collection